# Looking for an ERD (Viz) Tool for AVRO .avdl files

Tags: visualization, avro, erd

Does anyone have a recommendation for a ER visualization program that accepts .avdl files. Need it to natively accept avdl files versus the json format. I've looked at a few (Hackolade, Dataedo), but they all seem to only accept the .json files. If anyone has a recommendation, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dataedo from 9.3 supports Avro, Parquet, ORC and Delta Lakes. You can use it to discover and document schema, and visualize data model with ERDs.